# Placement of amsthm's proof and theorem environments

Tags: theorems, amsthm

Since when I started LaTeXing I've always wrote the proof environment inside the theorem, but I see many templates or answers in which first the theorem is ended and then the proof is begun.

Namely, what **I am used to do** is

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}% should anyway be loaded by amsart class
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Statement of the result
\begin{proof}
Proof of the result
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

whereas I see **most people rather writing**

```
...
\begin{theorem}
Statement of the result
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Proof of the result
\end{proof}
...
```

I was wondering whether one is a better practice than the other (for spacing/page breaks/references...) or if it is really just a matter of taste.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) because the actual theorem environments that you are using may be relevant (amsthm, ntheorem, ...). This said, I have always thought that the "correct" usage was to have the proof environment outside of the theorem-like environment. By the KISS principle, it is better not to nest environments unless you need to.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I added a MWE. I understand your point, but my thinking is that the proof is _part_ of the theorem, and if, e.g., I define a command inside the theorem it would be reasonable to being able to use it also in the proof, while without nesting it wouldn't be the case, since the command is 'lost' after `\end{theorem}`

Comment: The `proof` environment doesn't belong in the `theorem` environment.

Comment: The theorem environment provides formatting for the statement of the theorem. The proof environment provides the formatting for the proof, which is usually just the "opening" `Proof` and a symbol that marks the end of the proof. The statement of my theorems are usually in italics, so I definitely don't want to put the proof environment inside the theorem environment.

Comment: Although the `proof` environment overrides the italics of `theorem` and therefore everything looks as it should, you anyway convinced me that mine is not a good practice, thanks

Comment: @egreg: "The proof environment doesn't belong in the theorem environment". I don't understand why this is considered self evident. From a mathematical/semantical point of view it seems clear that a proof is _always_ bound to a theorem. It shouldn't exist in independence. The current amsthm practice ignores this. Say I want to reference to a proof of a theorem, it should be enough to use the label of the theorem. Are there any thm packages that take this into consideration?

Comment: @Michael It's very common to have text between the statement and its proof.